# Master Page Working in Visual Studio and not found in IIS

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HR.Default" %>
```

i found

```
Parser Error Message: The file '/Masterpage.Master' does not exist.
```

Master Page workign well in Main Directory Of Project in Visual STudio but not working in IIS.

Comment: How is IIS set up.  Is your site in the root folder or is it off the Default Website?

Comment: no in new root not under Default Website

Comment: @Fred can help please ?

Comment: Sorry I was called away.  Just to check something can you change `MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.Master"` to `MasterPageFile="Masterpage.Master"` and see if it solve the initial problem.

Comment: @Fred no didn't solve !

Comment: So if `Masterpage.Master` is in the same folder as the page you are trying to load I could well be a security issue or a server setup problem. If you look at the security setting of `Masterpage.Master` and the page you are trying to load are they the same?

Comment: Another thing to check is that the site is setup as an application.